# to delete characters in column names

Tags: r, rename

I have the following data for example

```
Ind var1_1 var2_2 var3_1 var4_2.......var100_1
 1   0      0       2      1             0
 2   2      0       1      0             2
```

And I want to rename the columns without the two characters at the back as follows

```
Ind var1 var2 var3 var4.......var100
 1   0     0    2    1           0
 2   2     0    1    0           2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `sub`.  We match the pattern `_` followed by one or more digits (`\\d+`) to the end (`$`) of the string and replace with `''`.

```
names(df) <- sub('_\\d+$', '', names(df))
```

Or as @David Arenburg mentioned, it can be one or more of any character (`.*`) after the `_` (which will match patterns such `var1_1`, `var1_d3533` etc.)

```
names(df) sub("_.*", "", df)
```

Or we use `paste` (@jogo's comment)

```
names(df) <- c("Ind", paste0("var", 1:100))
```

Comment: You could just do `sub("_.*", "", x)` in this case probably

Comment: or `names(df) <- c("Ind", paste0("var", 1:100))`