# R changing string pattern of column names

Tags: r

is there an easy order to change the string pattern of my column names? I've got a data set like the following, and I would like to have all the column names without the "_R1".

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
T_H_R1 T_S_R1 T_A_R1 T_V_R1 T_F_R1 
5 1 2 1 5 
3 1 3 3 4 
2 1 3 1 3  
4 2 5 5 3 
5 1 4 1 2 
")
```

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [to delete characters in column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34615460/to-delete-characters-in-column-names)

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sub` to match the `_R1` at the end (`$`) of the string of `names`, and replace with blank (`""`)

```
names(df) <- sub("_R1$", "", names(df))
names(df)
#[1] "T_H" "T_S" "T_A" "T_V" "T_F"
```